# Marketing Cloud : entry criteria conditions

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a Journey Builder with Entry Event on Salesforce Data.

On the Entry Criteria, I select the condition the Journey should trigger.

However it does not all the time.

On the attached screenshot :

[image]

If Close Date is null and KYC_Push=1 -> Trigger
If Close Date is not null and KYC_Push<>1 -> Trigger
If Close Date is not null and KYC_Push=1 -> **Not Trigger**

I tried several combination of AND / OR, still does not work.

Any idea please ?

Comment: Of course I would like the 3 ways to trigger !!

Comment: I think if fails because you have Account ID = Moongroup while the Accound ID in Salesforce is usually an alphanumeric 15/18 digit ID

Comment: Hello, no as said, the trigger does work for the 2 fields Close Date and KYC_Push individually.

Comment: is this configured as trigger on update or create? also if it is update trigger, when you test the 3rd scenario, what were values of Close Date and KYC_Push fields before you save the CRM record?